# IOS 10.3.2 crash with Notification Observer when removing observers

Tags: ios, swift

I am running into an odd issue on a Swift 3 based app and am trying to identify the best solution. Based on the crash log, it looks like Springboard is aborting due to the Watchdog framework finding a process taking too long to remove. What confuses me is that usually, this happens to me when there's a network call or something taking a significant amount of time to process ( more than usual).

In my example, I'm just disposing a video and removing the observer from a scene. The line of code that removes the observer is what seems to cause the app to crash, which it only does a handful of times. My question is - would the notification center observer logic be able to trigger a watchdog error like this? If so, what can I do about it?

Here's the faulting lines of code:

```
if((videoPlayer) != nil){        
    videoPlayer.pause();
    videoPlayer.removeFromParent();        
    videoPlayer = nil;        
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(currentScene); //line 176 referenced in log below     
}
```

Here's the crash log:

**Edit:**  Now with all threads.

```
Date/Time:           2017-06-29 08:46:28.3634 -0400
Launch Time:         2017-06-28 10:00:59.4686 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.2 (14F89)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b6b58e8 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b58577c _dispatch_ulock_wait + 48
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b5858a4 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 36
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b5834f0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 236
4   MediaToolbox                    0x00000001938ad4c8 FigVisualContextInvalidate + 156
5   AVFoundation                    0x000000019414dd70 -[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput dealloc] + 164
6   SpriteKit                       0x000000019be40998 SKCVideoNode::~SKCVideoNode() + 88
7   SpriteKit                       0x000000019be40a1c SKCVideoNode::~SKCVideoNode() + 12
8   SpriteKit                       0x000000019be07bc4 -[SKNode dealloc] + 48
9   coversapp                       0x00000001000685f8 removeVideo() -> () (media.swift:176)
10  coversapp                       0x0000000100046150 MainMenuScene.videoDone() -> () (MainMenuScene.swift:123)
11  coversapp                       0x00000001000418ac MainMenuScene.touchesBegan(Set<UITouch>, with : UIEvent?) -> () (MainMenuScene.swift:60)
12  coversapp                       0x0000000100041954 @objc MainMenuScene.touchesBegan(Set<UITouch>, with : UIEvent?) -> () (MainMenuScene.swift:0)
13  SpriteKit                       0x000000019bde8730 -[SKView touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 844
14  UIKit                           0x000000019281917c -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 1948
15  UIKit                           0x0000000192814728 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3192
16  UIKit                           0x00000001927e533c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
17  UIKit                           0x0000000192fdf014 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2400
18  UIKit                           0x0000000192fd9770 __handleEventQueue + 4268
19  UIKit                           0x0000000192fd9b9c __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 148
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c66942c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
21  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c668d9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
22  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c6669a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 744
23  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c596da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
24  GraphicsServices                0x000000018e000074 GSEventRunModal + 100
25  UIKit                           0x000000019284a058 UIApplicationMain + 208
26  coversapp                       0x000000010006a4ac main (AppDelegate.swift:12)
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018b5a559c start + 4

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b697224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b69709c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c668e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c666ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c596da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   Foundation                      0x000000018d0b0d74 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x000000018d0d1b44 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x00000001931d46a8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x000000018d1ae2d8 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b77d68c _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b77d59c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b77acb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 2 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b697224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b69709c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c668e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c666ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c596da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   AVFAudio                        0x00000001a6204540 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001a622a814 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 84
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b77d68c _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b77d59c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b77acb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b697224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b69709c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c668e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c666ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c596da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   AudioToolbox                    0x000000018f61a9fc GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6   AudioToolbox                    0x000000018f7ee4bc CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 84
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b77d68c _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b77d59c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b77acb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: FigVisualContext <0x170191fa0> image auto prune queue
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b6b58e8 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b58577c _dispatch_ulock_wait + 48
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b5858a4 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 36
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b5834f0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 236
4   MediaToolbox                    0x0000000193950f78 itemremotevc_copyCorrespondingItemForItem + 144
5   MediaToolbox                    0x0000000193953368 itemremotevc_copyImageForTimeCallback + 192
6   MediaToolbox                    0x00000001938ae2d4 FigVisualContextCopyImageForTime2 + 208
7   MediaToolbox                    0x00000001938ad96c figVisualContextAutoPrune + 220
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b5729a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b57f604 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 448
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b58bc1c _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 204
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b5748a0 _dispatch_source_invoke + 804
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b580964 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 560
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b5762cc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 884
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b582a50 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 540
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b5827d0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b77b100 _pthread_wqthread + 1096
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b77acac start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.coremedia.visualContextSyncQueue
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b6b4e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b77c814 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   CoreMedia                       0x000000018ef940dc WaitOnCondition + 16
3   CoreMedia                       0x000000018ef94024 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 168
4   CoreMedia                       0x000000018f03e5dc FigReadWriteLockLockForWrite + 84
5   MediaToolbox                    0x00000001938adcb0 FigVisualContextSetProducerCallbacks + 56
6   MediaToolbox                    0x0000000193952e94 __itemremote_Invalidate_block_invoke + 92
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b5729a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b57fee0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
9   MediaToolbox                    0x000000019384bbcc itemremote_Invalidate + 348
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c5961d0 __CFSetApplyFunction_block_invoke + 24
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c596010 CFBasicHashApply + 132
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c595f40 CFSetApplyFunction + 224
13  MediaToolbox                    0x000000019386b7b8 playerremote_Invalidate + 192
14  MediaToolbox                    0x00000001938f219c playerasync_InvalidateOnQueue + 220
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b5729a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b580ad4 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b5762cc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 884
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b580fa8 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 344
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b582a50 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 540
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b5827d0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b77b100 _pthread_wqthread + 1096
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b77acac start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: what version of swift are you using?

Comment: Good point. I'm currently using Swift 3.

Comment: This: `Code 0x8badf00d` is an indicator that you're not responding quickly enough on the main thread.  (Usually related to background/foreground transitions, but not necessarily.)  The lock you show on the main thread looks suspicious.  Check other threads for conflicting locks.

Comment: Thanks Phillip, that makes me wonder if if it's the "FigVisualContext" logic that's occurring on thread 4. I have updated the original question if you'd like to see the extra detail.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful to anyone else, but I believe I was able to improve the performance of my app by reversing the order of operations. Initially, the app was disposing of the video, then removing observers. I flipped it and now the app seems to stay up longer.